# Decreasing of a charge amount and its effects on a capacitor

Tags: charge, voltage, capacitance

There is an equation of charge amount on a capacitor you may know;

[image: Capacitor charge]

This graph above shows the charge amount. And according to the book "Fundamentals of Electric Circuit from CK Alexander", in equation 6.2 and page 217. It says capacitance doesn't depend on charge or applied voltage. It depends on physical dimensions of the capacitor like surface area of paltes and their distance. **And I know that my capacitance is constant.**

So, I am applying a square wave signal (can be seen below Appendix-1) across a capacitor and changing its frequency. When I increase frequency which means decreasing its period, according to the charge amount fromula above in graph the charge amount decreases *(period decreased and **'t'** decreases in formula)*. Then what happens? Capacitance is constant. Applied voltage is constant for a certain time. What results?

In my opinion; when I increase frequency, conversely say decreasing period of a square wave signal, the charge amount decreases. That also means charge amount on capacitor plate decreases. If my opinion is correct, what its effect on capacitor?

Finally, do you think this results as decreasing of a capacitor voltage?

Appendix 1: Square wave signal waveform

[image: sqaure wave signal]

Appendix 2: Capacitor charging and discharging simulation in 5 kHz frequency square wave applied voltage ( blue - power supply waveform / green - capacitor voltage changes )

[image: 5 kHz]

Appendix 3: Capacitor charging and discharging simulation in 20 kHz frequency square wave applied voltage ( blue - power supply waveform / green - capacitor voltage changes )

[image: 20 kHz]

Comment: Your first figure is only valid when you apply a voltage to an initially uncharged capacitor. Besides that, you already have simulation results that seem to answer your question. What more do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know that if my opinion is correct, which is when I increase frequency the charge amount on plates decrease, and the reason for the decrease in capacitor voltage is due to charge amount?

Comment: Capacitor charge is always proportional to its voltage (with the capacitance being the proportionality factor). One is not the cause of the other, they just come together. The charge is just the voltage multiplied by capacitance, and is a function of time in this case. Are you asking about the average charge? The charge at the end of the first voltage pulse? What exactly isn't clear to you in the simulation results?

Comment: The thing I don't understand or not being satisfied is when my charge (Q) decrease due to increase of frequency of the square wave signal, what happens to capacitor? Because my capacitance (C) is constant, my voltage difference between plates is constant for a certain time. But the charge amount is decreasing because of frequency increasing. What happens to capacitor? What changes in it? And how the decrease of charge amount result in? Sorry for not being clear. Maybe my knowledge is not good enough to express myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure about the data that you have presented.

I have simulated the circuit using [Spinning Numbers sandbox](https://spinningnumbers.org/circuit-sandbox/index.html?value=%5B%5B%22v%22%2C%5B88%2C64%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22square(0%2C1%2C10%2C50)%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A0%7D%2C%5B%222%22%2C%220%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22c%22%2C%5B216%2C104%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22c%22%3A%221m%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A1%7D%2C%5B%221%22%2C%220%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22r%22%2C%5B216%2C24%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22r%22%3A%221k%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A2%7D%2C%5B%222%22%2C%221%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B88%2C64%2C88%2C24%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B88%2C24%2C216%2C24%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B88%2C112%2C88%2C152%5D%5D%2C%5B%22g%22%2C%5B152%2C152%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22_json_%22%3A6%7D%2C%5B%220%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B88%2C152%2C152%2C152%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B216%2C152%2C152%2C152%5D%5D%2C%5B%22s%22%2C%5B216%2C88%2C0%5D%2C%7B%22color%22%3A%22red%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%220%22%2C%22_json_%22%3A9%7D%2C%5B%221%22%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B216%2C72%2C216%2C88%5D%5D%2C%5B%22w%22%2C%5B216%2C104%2C216%2C88%5D%5D%2C%5B%22view%22%2C0%2C0%2C2%2C%2250%22%2C%2210%22%2C%221G%22%2C%22%22%2C%22100%22%2C%225%22%2C%221000%22%5D%5D) using three different square wave frequencies.

[image]

You will note that the mean "final" voltage tends to the mean voltage of the square wave which in this case is half the peak value?

Note what happens when the duty cycle is change to $75\%$.

[image]

The mean voltage across the capacitor tends to $75\%$ of the peak voltage of the square wave.

Comment: That is obviously true, your simulation and results are totally correct. Because when you increase duty cycle value, your rms voltage value is increase. rms value means that the effective value. Therefore, increase of duty cycle value causes to increase of effective voltage value. But I don't consider duty cycle value in my question. I consider, frequency.. the frequency of square wave signal. And in my opinion, frequency doesnt effect rms value of applied voltage.

Comment: @NafiCanEreli  I did show that the rms voltage was independent of frequency. How is it that in your simulation you you found that from a $2\,\rm V$ peak square wave the rms value was $0.5\,\rm V$?

Answer (score 0):

> I am applying a square wave signal ... across a capacitor

You are not. You are applying a square wave across the combination of a capacitor and a resistor. That's not the same thing.

> according to the charge amount fromula above in graph the charge amount decreases

The graph shows the charge that would be transferred by a single square pulse (and when the capacitor starts fully discharged), not by a periodic series of pulses.

> Applied voltage is constant for a certain time. What results?

That is exactly what the "charge amount graph" shows you. The charge increases asymptotically with an exponential decay towards a fully charged state ($Q=CV_b$).

> when I increase frequency, conversely say decreasing period of a square wave signal, the charge amount decreases. That also means charge amount on capacitor plate decreases.

This is correct. With a shorter pulse, the time variable on the "amount of charge" graph is smaller at the end of the pulse and just as the graph shows you the final charge is less.

> If my opinion is correct, what its effect on capacitor?

The final charge (charge at the moment when the square pulse ends) is not as much. But that doesn't mean that the nature of the capacitor or its capacitance has changed.